# Why will Typescript allow incorrect overloaded function returns?

Tags: typescript, overloading

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361438/950099) a Typescript maintainer gives a simple example of how [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) works in Typescript and how it differs to languages with actual overloading.

However modifying their example to the following still compiles:

```
function numberStringSwitch(x: string): number;
function numberStringSwitch(x: number): string;
function numberStringSwitch(x: string | number) {
    return x;
}
```

This seems to me like it shouldn't be valid; why is it allowed? How do I make this example fail to compile like I'd expect?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGEBbARgUwE4GUrYxgDmuA7jFBABYAUAHgFyIDOBRxAlMyhjgNwAoUJFgJkaLHnYlylGgx6Sc3VjOJCR0eEl5T8hWRSp0maw8UQAfCX2ydEAb0GJXibJighsSekIC+gkA), TS 3.6.3

Comment: Any is assignable to all types and assignable from all types. That behavior is exactly what is expected.

Comment: In the docs it says "Note that the `function pickCard(x): any` piece is not part of the overload list, so it only has two overloads: one that takes an object and one that takes a number.", so how would I write the above so it errors?
Removing both the `any`s still compiles

Comment: Not sure if I'm just not getting you, but that doesn't seem to fix it on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGEBbARgUwE4GUrYxgDmuA7jFBABYAUAHgFyIDOBRxAlMyhjgNwAoUJFgJkaLHnYlylGgx6Sc3VjOJCR0eEl5T8hWRSp0maw8UQAfCX2ydEAb0GJXibJighsSekIC+gkA)

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14515) seems relevant. Especially Ryan's [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14515#issuecomment-284827139) _We also don't have any mechanism for "if x is T then y is U" inferences._

Comment: That playground link doesn't error because it is valid according to the declared types

Comment: But how is it valid? It's obviously going to return the wrong type in all overload cases

Comment: I saw this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58386045/return-type-never-if-an-optional-parameter-is-given-to-be-a-specific-value the other day. Maybe this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty simple - there are 2 possible inputs to your `numberStringSwitch` method - `string` or `number` - and that is exactly what [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) are in typescript. This means that you can write your "implementation" method using union signature which is `string | number` - it's important because when you are writing body of your method you need to have safely typed input which represents union of all your overload inputs (in this case either `string` or `number`). You could of course use `any` like they did, but it's union is also an option (honestly more readable option for me).

You can try to use change your input to something that is not in your overloads methods and you'll get error

```
// error
function numberStringSwitch(x: string | Date) {
    return x;
}
```

But if you add another overload with `Date` and add it's parameter type to final union, it works:

```
// works
function numberStringSwitch(x: string): number;
function numberStringSwitch(x: number): string;
function numberStringSwitch(x: Date): string;
function numberStringSwitch(x: string | number | Date) {
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure this answers my question though. What do you mean by "error" and "works"? Your "error" example compiles just fine without error and your "works" is just another example of the issue I'm asking about. _Why_ does it work when it obviously violates all overloads?

Comment: It does just the opposite - it unifies all overloads. Option 1 is string, option 2 is number, option 3 is date - when you are writing implementation it can be one of all those types so you need to write "string OR number OR date" which is exactly that (above union). I'm really not sure which part you don't understand.

Comment: I get the input union part, that's fine. The part I'm confused about is `return x` doesn't satisfy `string -> number`, `number -> string`, or `Date -> string`, why doesn't the compiler catch that my function implementation is violating any (or in this case all) of my overloads?

Comment: Because implementation function signature basically "doesn't exist" - you always call one of the top functions so the return type is known to the caller. You can set return type as number | string, and it would still compile successfully. You can look it this way - top overloads are for callers of the method, while the last one is for the writer of the function so he can easily see which types can input/output be.

Comment: That's what I was after. So the only remaining question is is there a trick I can use to make it more safe?